# Randomly assign a value to a specificed number of rows in a feature class in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor

I have several feature classes, each with a million or so rows. In each of these feature classes I have an attribute ("STATE"), the value of which I want to randomly assign to one or another state (so represented as a binary - 1 or 0).

However For each of these feature classes, there are only a specific number of rows (events) that can be assigned 1. Does anyone have a quick means of taking this field (currently, for all rows [STATE] = 0), and randomly assigning x number of rows to be [STATE] = 1. Say, turn 25,000 of the million rows to be 1 rather than 0?

I have tried using cursor but I keep failing at it.

Comment: It would be helpful to show an example of the data you are working with as well as the intended output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below assumes you have ArcGIS 10.1 or later and can use data access cursors (da cursors).  The da cursors run 10 times faster than the original cursor syntax that you were using.

Here is the way to do this using the random library sample method.  You must supply the value you want for the sampled records chosen and the value you want for the items not sampled, so that an existing randomized set of records can be changed to a new randomized sampling each time the script is run.  Your field is only added if it does not exist, but other inputs and validation checks designed to create or apply the appropriate field type should be done if this code was used to create a tool that got direct user input.

```
from time import strftime  

print "Start script: " + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  

import arcpy, random

# User inputs.  Convert to parameters for a tool.  Could deal with field type too.
ws = r"C:\Users\XXX\DATABASE.gdb"
fc = "test"
updateField = "STATE"
sampleSize = 25000
sampledValue = 1
unsampledValue = 0

# set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = ws

# If the field does not exist, add it.  Field type could be part of user input.
if not updateField.upper() in [x.name.upper() for x in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, updateField, "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE")
    print "Added Field: " + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  

fields =  ["OID@", updateField] # ObjectID unique values and update field  

# create a list from the fc
values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (fields))]

# Get the total item count in the list
rlen = len(values)

print "Read " + str(rlen) + " Records: " + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  

# Make sure the sample size is in range
if sampleSize > rlen:
    sampleSize = rlen
elif sampleSize < 1:
    sampleSize = 1

# Get a random sample from the list
rand = random.sample(values, sampleSize)

print "Sampled " + str(sampleSize) + " Records: " + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as updateRows:  
    for updateRow in updateRows:
        # Update value depending on whether or not ObjectID is in the random list.
        if updateRow[0] in rand:
            # ObjectID was sampled  
            updateRow[1] = sampledValue
        else:
            # ObjectID was not sampled
            updateRow[1] = unsampledValue
        updateRows.updateRow(updateRow)  

print "Updated " + updateField + " values: " + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

You could make your sample size based on a percentage of your total records as an alternative to a fixed number.

```
# User inputs.  Convert to parameters for a tool.  Could deal with field type too.
ws = r"C:\Users\XXX\DATABASE.gdb"
fc = "test"
updateField = "STATE"
samplePercent = .025
sampledValue = 1
unsampledValue = 0
```

## ...

```
# Get the total item count in the list
rlen = len(values)

sampleSize = int(rlen * samplePercent)
```

You could alternatively increase the randomization by changing the code to an upper and lower range of sample sizes you would allow and let the random.sample method choose your actual sample size each time you ran the code.  Here is an example of what the user inputs would look like if you did that with sample size fixed number values:

```
# User inputs.  Convert to parameters for a tool.  Could deal with field type too.
ws = r"C:\Users\XXX\DATABASE.gdb"
fc = "test"
updateField = "STATE"
lowerSampleSize = 10000
upperSampleSize = 25000
sampleSize = random.sample(xrange(lowerSampleSize, upperSampleSize, 1), 1)
sampledValue = 1
unsampledValue = 0
```

Here is an example of what the user inputs could look like if you did that with sample size percentage values:

```
# User inputs.  Convert to parameters for a tool.  Could deal with field type too.
ws = r"C:\Users\XXX\DATABASE.gdb"
fc = "test"
updateField = "STATE"
lowerSamplePercent = .02
upperSamplePercent = .03
sampledValue = 1
unsampledValue = 0
```

## ...

```
# Get the total item count in the list
rlen = len(values)

sampleSize = int(rlen * random.sample(xrange(lowerSamplePercent, upperSamplePercent, .00001), 1))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is much more robust than the method that I came up with

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an answer myself in a fit of pique, using the OBJECTID field as a delimiter - happy for any other suggestions from people!

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\XXX\DATABASE.gdb'
#create state class
input_file = "test"
arcpy.AddField_management(input_file, "STATE", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE")

fc = "test"
field1 = "OBJECTID"
field2 = "STATE"

#assign only the first 2000 records to be [STATE] = 1
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
row = cursor.next()
while row.getValue(field1) < 2001:
    # assign value to 1
    row.setValue(field2, 1)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    row = cursor.next()
```